# onclick isn't working in ie

Tags: jquery, html, fancybox

I have the following code:

```
<input class="button button-blue" type="button" onclick="jQuery.fancybox.close(); " value="Close">
```

In ie when I click the button the onclick event handler doesn't work. "doesn't work" meaning that the fancy box dialog doesn't close.  But as soon as I make a change to the onclick value (ie add a space after jQuery.fancybox.close()) using f12 then the onclick event handler starts to work.

Note:

- There are no scripting errors
- Works fine on chrome and firefox
- Appears that any change to the onclick value will cause the event handler to start working.

Any suggestion on how to troubleshoot?

```
$.fancybox({
      'modal': true,
       height: '10%', minHeight: '60',
       'content': "<div style=\"margin:10px;\">"
       + 'Your message has been sent.'
       + "<div style=\"text-align:center;margin-top:10px;\"><input     class=\"button button-blue\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"jQuery.fancybox.close();  Backbone.pubSub.trigger('myContentShowHide');\" value=\"My Content\"></div>"
       + "<div style=\"text-align:center;margin-top:10px;\"><input     class=\"button button-blue\" type=\"button\" onclick=\"jQuery.fancybox.close();   \" value=\"Close\"></div>"
});
```

Comment: You already have jQuery... have you considered not using inline `onclick` handlers?

Comment: ok, thanks.  I'll try removing the inline event handler.

Comment: As far as I can tell, it works for me, even on IE7 http://jsfiddle.net/pzosotpx/show/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have jQuery installed and it's designed specifically to normalize any cross-browser issues.

So get rid of the inline event handlers and use jQuery event handlers instead.  Since the button element does not yet exist when this code is called, you'll need to use the event-delegation approach...

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('body').on('click', 'input.button[value="Close"]', function() {
        $.fancybox.close();
    });

});
```

See:  http://api.jquery.com/on/

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6k1o7amL/**

Comment: I appreciate the demo.  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: The fancybox dialog is added to the page after it is loaded.  It's a dialog box displayed after the user has taken action.  If I add the script above in the main page wouldn't if fail because the button hasn't been added to the DOM yet.   I updated the original question with the script that adds the dialog.

Comment: @bradley4, then you simply need to use event-delegation.  See my modified answer.

Comment: Thanks Sparky. I won't be able to verify the fix until Monday once it's in intg.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using inline event handlers. Bind event to button using jQuery like so:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){

   jQuery('.button').click(function(e){
      jQuery.fancybox.close();
      e.preventDefault();
   });

});
```

Comment: `.preventDefault()` is supposed to be the *first* line, not the last.  Regardless, it's a `type="button"`, so IMO there's no need for a `.preventDefault()`.  Also, `document` does not belong within quotes.

Comment: Finally, your jQuery selector will target ***any/all*** buttons with the `.button` class.

Comment: @Sparky, preventDefault is just in case. :) Why does it have to be the first line, I never had issues with putting it in the event block wherever... Agree with the button's selector though, yours is a more precise targeting.

Comment: If you're calling this method to block the default behavior, it only stands to reason that you'd want to do this as soon as the event is triggered.  Besides, it's how the demo code is written:  http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/

Comment: @Sparky, Point taken.